# JanusGraph build failed (TinkerPop 3.2.4)

Tags: maven, build, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I cloned JanusGraph repo (d6b3d42) and build it without any problem. I need to use it with ThinkerPop 3.2.4 so I changed its version in pom.xml file. Then I run `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`.

---

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.github.jeremyh:jBCrypt:jar:jbcrypt-0.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] JanusGraph: Distributed Graph Database ............. SUCCESS [  0.563 s]
[INFO] JanusGraph-Core: Core Library for JanusGraph ....... FAILURE [  0.275 s]
[INFO] JanusGraph-Test: Test Suite for JanusGraph ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph CodePipelines CI: Distributed release testing. SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-BerkeleyJE: Distributed Graph Database .. SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Cassandra: Distributed Graph Database ... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-CQL: Distributed Graph Database ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-ElasticSearch: Distributed Indexing Support SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-HBase: Parent Module .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-HBase: Version-independent Core ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-HBase: 0.98 Compatibility Shim .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-HBase: 1.x Compatibility Shim ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-HBase: Universal binary ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Hadoop: Parent Module ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Hadoop: Version-independent Core ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Hadoop: 2.x Compatibility Shim .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Hadoop: Universal binary ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Lucene: Indexing Support ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-All: Complete JanusGraph Distribution ... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Solr: Distributed Indexing Support ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Dist: Tar and Zip Archives .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Dist: Archive with Hadoop 2 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Doc: AsciiDoc Manual for JanusGraph ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] JanusGraph-Examples: Examples for JanusGraph ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Example-Common: Common Graph Code for Examples ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Example-BerkeleyJE: BerkeleyJE Storage, Lucene Index SKIPPED
[INFO] Example-Cassandra: C* Thrift Storage, ES Index ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Example-Cql: C* CQL Storage, ES Index .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Example-HBase: HBase Storage, Solr Index ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Example-RemoteGraph: Example with RemoteGraph ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Example-TinkerGraph: Example with TinkerGraph ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.557 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-27T16:44:59+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project janusgraph-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.janusgraph:janusgraph-core:jar:0.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.github.jeremyh:jBCrypt:jar:jbcrypt-0.4 in http://download.oracle.com/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oracleReleases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :janusgraph-core
```

How can I build JanusGraph with TinkerPop 3.2.4 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the root `pom.xml` to add the Jitpack repository:

```
     <repository>
        <!-- for com.github.jeremyh:jBCrypt:jar -->
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <name>JitPack Package Repository</name>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

This repository was removed the `pom.xml` because newer versions of Apache TinkerPop do not have this dependency.

Reference from [janusgraph-users](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/janusgraph-users/kGCfFcgE2Vs/50KgDvwcBwAJ) Google group:

> That dependency isn't found in Maven central, jbcrypt-0.4 is found in the jitpack.io repository. You'll need to add a remote repository for it. You could use the `dependency:get` command:

```
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories="https://jitpack.io" -Dartifact="com.github.jeremyh:jBCrypt:jbcrypt-0.4"
```

When you run the command above, you will download the required `jBCrypt` dependency into your local Maven repository so that you can continue to build JanusGraph. If you're interested in [building a distribution zip](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-dist/README.md), similar to the ones you can find on the JanusGraph [downloads](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases) page, use this command:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.skip=true -Pjanusgraph-release
```

Then you can find the distribution zip under `janusgraph-dist/janusgraph-dist-hadoop-2/target/janusgraph-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.zip`.

Comment: I used above command and i get "BUILD SUCCESS" meessage. Dose it mean that the whole JanusGraph was build? How `mvn dependency` is related to `mvn clean install`?

Comment: I did exactly as you write above and I (after execution `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.skip=true -Pjanusgraph-release`) get the same error.

Comment: I did steps as you suggested and I build JanusGraph. It still didn't solve my problem. I get an error when I run my app (based on python goblin ogm) which works on TinkerPop 3.2.4. How can I check which version of TinkerPop I start with bin/janusgraph.sh start command?

Comment: from the Gremlin Console `Gremlin.version()` or from the Bash shell `ls lib/gremlin-core*.jar`

Comment: Gremlin version is 3.2.4 as I expected. Your solution is definitely correct. Thank you for all your assistance.